# WebView: open in external browser and not in the app

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using javascript to redirect a page to another, in my app, on a webView:

This is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        setTimeout(function () {
           window.location.replace('.com.my.app.services.MyClass'); 
        }, 3000);


    });
```

But, If I click on the back button of my device, in example, during the js loading on the submit of the login, cause the opening of the external browser.
Is an html page, linked with wicket, and I have this problem ONLY with Android.

I'm very new with all of this.

I tried, to avoid the opening of the browser, this:

```
var visibile;

function ShowIf(urlOfThePage) { //append this on wicket and called when  the user submit on login
    if (visibile === "visible") {
        window.location.replace(urlOfThePage);
    } else{

    }
}


(function() {
  var hidden = "hidden";

  // Standards:
  if (hidden in document)
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
  // IE 9 and lower:
  else if ("onfocusin" in document)
    document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
  // All others:
  else
    window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide
    = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;


  function onchange (evt) {
    var v = "visible", h = "hidden",
        evtMap = {
          focus:v, focusin:v, pageshow:v, blur:h, focusout:h, pagehide:h
        };

    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.type in evtMap)
     visibile = evtMap[evt.type];
    else
      visibile = this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible";
  }

  // set the initial state (but only if browser supports the Page Visibility API)
  if( document[hidden] !== undefined )
    onchange({type: document[hidden] ? "blur" : "focus"});
})();
```

//login.java, on wicket:

```
  [...]

    private void signIn(AjaxRequestTarget target, Class<? extends WebPage> ctarget)
        {
          // Get session info
          CWSSession session = (CWSSession)getSession();



             // Sign the user in
              if (session.signIn(getUsername(), getPassword()))
              {
                if (ctarget == null)
                  ctarget = GameQuestionAnswers.class;
                // continueToOriginalDestination();
            target.appendJavaScript(
                    "ShowIf('"
                    + urlFor(ctarget, new PageParameters()) + "')");
           /*here there is the url */
          }
    [...]
```

If the user, tap on the back button, the page should be "hidden" and do the trick, avoiding Android to open the browser. 
But is not working...

Where is my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: where is your android webview code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line for your webview.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry, but I don't know exactly how should I add this line of code.
I found this line in other so answer, but they where just for whose who were coding using only android.

Comment: Where is the webview. As you said you are using webview. I don;t see webview in your code.